# What exactly is a p'-group?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, notation

In the context of finite group theory I understand that $p$-group is a group whose order is a power of $p$ ($p$ a prime number) but I am unclear on the exact definition of a $p'$-group.

This notation is used in Gorenstein's book "Finite Groups", and while the book contains a brief explanation of the notation used I am still confused. I'll write the explanation here, just in case it helps:

"The complementary set of primes to $\pi$ will be denoted $\pi'$. Thus we also have the notion of $\pi'$- and $p'$- elements as well as $\pi'$- and p'- groups. For example a $2'$-element is simply an element of odd order.

I guess what I can't understand is what is a complementary set of primes in this context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Complementary set of primes: all the other primes.

Concretely, if $\mathscr P=\{$all primes$\}$, then 
$$\pi'=\mathscr P\setminus\pi,\quad p'=\mathscr P\setminus\{p\}\,.$$

A $p'$-group consists of elements that all avoid the prime $p$ in their orders.